# How to store all scraped stats moment before spider closes?

Tags: scrapy

I want to store all the stats collected from the spider into a single output file stored as json format. However, I get this error:

> 'MemoryStatsCollector' object has no attribute 'get_all'

: The documentation mentions that `stats.get_all` is how you get all the stores. What is the correct method of implementation for this?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy import crawler
import jsonlines

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stats'

    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def __init__(self, stats):
       self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        #spider = super(TestSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        stat = cls(crawler.stats)
        crawler.signals.connect(stat.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return stat

    def spider_closed(self):
        #self.stats = stat
        txt_file = 'some_text.jl'
        with jsonlines.open(txt_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.stats.get_all())
        

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse
            )
    def parse(self, response):
        content = response.xpath('//div[@class = "row"]')
        for items in content:
            yield {
                'some_items_links':items.xpath(".//a//@href").get()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is no `get_all` for the method and instead I had to input `get_stats()`, the documentation provides a few examples of some:

- stats.get_value()
- stats.get_stats()
- stats.max_value()/stats.min_value()
- stats.inc_value()
- stats.set_value()

Some further information provided in the documentation for [stats](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html).

The working part:

```
    def spider_closed(self):
        #self.stats = stat
        txt_file = 'some_text.jl'
        with jsonlines.open(txt_file, 'w') as f:
            # f.write(f'{self.stats.get_all()}') --- Changed
            f.write(f'{self.stats.get_stats()}')
```

Output:

```
{
    "log_count/INFO": 10,
    "log_count/DEBUG": 3,
    "start_time": datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 6, 16, 16, 30, 553373),
    "memusage/startup": 59895808,
    "memusage/max": 59895808,
    "scheduler/enqueued/memory": 1,
    "scheduler/enqueued": 1,
    "scheduler/dequeued/memory": 1,
    "scheduler/dequeued": 1,
    "downloader/request_count": 1,
    "downloader/request_method_count/GET": 1,
    "downloader/request_bytes": 223,
    "downloader/response_count": 1,
    "downloader/response_status_count/200": 1,
    "downloader/response_bytes": 2086,
    "httpcompression/response_bytes": 11053,
    "httpcompression/response_count": 1,
    "response_received_count": 1,
    "item_scraped_count": 1,
    "elapsed_time_seconds": 0.34008,
    "finish_time": datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 6, 16, 16, 30, 893453),
    "finish_reason": "finished",
}
```